# How to avoid Javascript making Android WebView unresponsive?

Tags: android, android-webview, chromium

I recently ran into an issue where a web app is opened inside a WebView and starts executing, in short, a never-ending Javascript rendering loop. Exiting the WebView while the loop is going and calling `destroy()` does not seem to terminate the Javascript call, leading to any instance of WebView afterwards unable to load anything.

I believe this happens because there is only one renderer process and Javascript runs on a single thread. Is there anyway to defend against this on the Android side? In a hybrid app, having a web developer unintentionally break the whole native experience seems suboptimal.

I expected closing a WebView to effectively stop any pending Javascript execution, but it kept going and making the whole renderer process unresponsive.

Comment: Share your webview code.

Answer (score 0):

Given below infinite loop script

```kotlin
webView.evaluateJavascript(
    """
        while (true) {}
    """.trimIndent(),
    null
)
```

I can terminate the rendering process by calling [WebViewRenderProcess.terminate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewRenderProcess#terminate())

```kotlin
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    webView.webViewRenderProcess?.terminate()
}
```

Be careful, `WebViewClient.onRenderProcessGone` must be handled properly first as described by the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/webapps/managing-webview#termination-handle) for all WebViews inside the app (ads SDKs included). Otherwise, the app will crash.